# Topology rules on multi story buildings using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, topology, feature-class

I would like to run some topology rules to find snapping errors in our polygons but I am running in to the problem where we are working on multi story buildings with every polygon regardless of floor is stored in one feature class.

We separate the floors out by adding layers with definition queries.

From what I can see I can only create topology rules (like "boundaries must be covered by") for a feature class and not a queried layer.

In the screen shot provided the grey polygon is not snapped correctly to the North West most corner of the only polygon completely in frame of the screenshot.  Running a boundary covered by will easily spot this error but only if I disassemble the feature class so that each floor is on its own feature class.  Needless to say the more floors involved the more tedious this becomes.

Not to mention that I must then reassemble the separated feature classes back into one as this is how the deliverable is required to be.

There is one feature class for the room polygons and one for the CAD line work.

Is there an easier way to find gaps like this without separating the feature classes to run the topology then putting the separated classes back together to produce the deliverable?

[image: Screenshot of a problem area]

Answer (score 5):

You can define the floors as [subtypes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005r00000003000000) of one layer and then apply the topology rules between subtypes. Topology rules can be defined between subtypes of features in one or another feature class. This could be used, for example, to require street features to be connected to other street features at both ends, except in the case of streets belonging to the cul-de-sac or dead-end subtypes